# Get underlying Socket for HttpRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

I would like to get access to the underlying Socket in an HttpRequest to check on the socket for socket options.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Socket s = Request.????;
    Object result = s.GetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,xxx);
    /// do something else
}
```

Any idea how to get this information ?

Note that the code is running on Azure.

Comment: it doesn't matter whether it is Azure or not. All you want is to get the Socket out from HttpRequest object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The `HttpRequest` has no `Socket` property. Please note the HttpRequest / Response classes exist to abstract the rawness of HTTP away from your code, so I wouldnt be surprised if there is no way to access the socket object, if that even exists in the HttpRequest class. What if you start writing to the socket and _then_ let ASP.NET generate the response? What socket option exactly are you looking for? Perhaps it's obtainable in a different manner.

Comment: I want to read the TypeOfService property from an incoming HTTP Request. This is part of the IP header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I had to do a workaround. I created a TCPListener on a different port, which handles a basic HTTP request at a lower level, but captures the information in the socket. The main HTTP does a redirection to this one to figure out the ToS.

```
private void HandleAsyncConnection(IAsyncResult result)
{
  // Accept connection 
  TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)result.AsyncState;
  TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);
  client.Client.GetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.TypeOfService);
  ...
  // and then I do a redirect in HTTP
}
```