# IIS Get Socket for HttpRequest Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I want to have access to underlying Socket for HttpRequest In asp.net app,

Websocket is not supported on some os, so I want to have access the socket so I can implement it by myself.

is it possible to get socket ?

I also read this:[underlying Socket for HttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764773/get-underlying-socket-for-httprequest)

Comment: It is impossible. For ASP.NET web apps, there is no such `Socket` object, as the actual socket operations are done by IIS, and ASP.NET solely sees the requests.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks , is it possible to write a module or ... to achieve this purpose?

Comment: Windows HTTP/HTTPS component is a system driver `http.sys`, so unless you write your own driver to replace it (which is only technically feasible, while practically impossible due to various factors). Instead, use a framework like SignalR please, and then WebSockets is no longer mandate.